# How to add ID property to Html.BeginForm() in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I want to validate my form using jquery but it doesn't have an `ID` property as of now how to add it to the form in asp.net mvc? I am using this...

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
```

and my jquery validator plugin takes this,

```
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
```

Now i want to give id as `signupform`... Any suggestion...

Comment: Good question, has nothing to do with jquery

Answer (score 389, accepted):

This should get the id added.

ASP.NET MVC 5 and lower:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "signupform" }))
   { } %>
```

ASP.NET Core: You can [use tag helpers in forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms) to avoid the odd syntax for setting the id.

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post" id="signupform" role="form"></form>
```

Comment: why action and controller are null there? Could you explain it plz?

Comment: I don't know where you want to post the form so I just made them null.

Comment: Also having the action and controller set to null saves you from having to hard-code them.  This is useful if you have your form within a partial view and that partial is used within multiple views like Create and Edit.

Comment: Where does one find the API or documentation for all of the html helpers? For example where do  find out what the parameters stand for?

Comment: That FormMethod param gets me every time - I go for null/string.empty - my go-to overloads, but can never remember the right order to get the id/class attribute into the form tag.

Comment: @JasonRowe Is there a way in which I can add Class and ID ?

Comment: @Zapnologica Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542%28v=vs.108%29.aspx. The htmlAttributes parameter consists of an object that contains name/value pairs. new { id = "myid", @class="myclass" }

Comment: I really think you should explain in your answer that the two ``null`` parameters are meant to be replaced with the actual controller/action names, since people may think it's allowed to set them to null and that the framework will automatically find the matching post method.

Answer (score 7):

I've added some code to my project, so it's more convenient.

HtmlExtensions.cs:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formId)
        {
            return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = formId });
        }

        public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formId, FormMethod method)
        {
            return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, method, new { id = formId });
        }
    }
}
```

MySignupForm.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("signupform")) 
{
    @* Some fields *@
}
```

Comment: For .NET5 and .NET6 it's IHtmlHelper rather than HtmlHelper

Answer (score 6):

In *System.Web.Mvc.Html*  ( in *System.Web.Mvc.dll* ) the begin form is defined like:- [Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542(v=vs.118).aspx)

> BeginForm ( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string
>   controllerName,     object routeValues, FormMethod method, object
>   htmlAttributes)

**Means you should use like this :**

> Html.BeginForm( string actionName, string controllerName,object
>   routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)

**So, it worked in MVC 4**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { @id = string.Empty }, FormMethod.Post,
    new { @id = "signupform" }))
{
    <input id="TRAINER_LIST" name="TRAINER_LIST" type="hidden" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

Answer (score 6):

May be a bit late but in my case i had to put the id in the 2nd anonymous object.
This is because the 1st one is for route values i.e the return Url.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {  ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "signupform", role = "form" }))
```

Hope this can help somebody :)